# Facebook lead integration with Webhooks gives error session has been invalidated

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I am a Laravel developer, currently working on a CRM. I have successfully implemented Facebook lead integration with webhook. The long access token generation and lead accessing are working correctly. But some time for some users there is an error while accessing the lead data "Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user changed their password or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.". How can I fix this issue?

The error message returned from Facebook is given below.

{
"error":{
"message":"Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user changed their password or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.",
"type":"OAuthException",
"code":190,
"error_subcode":460,
"fbtrace_id":"AVsp5upoGmfjxr_YGoCH7v5"
}
}

Facebook has given an error handling method and it is not working for me.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What exactly is not working with the solution provided by FB? In these cases, what is the solution, do they need to generate a new Token?

Comment: In the documentation, they say we need to generate a new token and that can be done by the server end if the user did not remove the page access. As of the document we will get a variable named 'code' from the request and by using it we can create a new token. but I don't get such a variable with the request. they are only providing the leadgenid, adid, adsetid like that

Comment: Did you send the user through the login flow? It sounds like you were just trying to execute that code on its own, of course in that case there won't be any `code` parameter.